# Calculating Cost of Postage based on Postcode

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to find a way to calculate the cost of Postage based on Postcodes entered into a Form - I am looking at having the prices stored in a database possibly like for example: Postcode is 4000 to 4999 postage will be $8.00 or Postcode is 2000 to 2999 postage will be $4.65  Would it be if, if/else??? if/ or??? Not sure...  Thanks in advance

Comment: Store the different postages in a separate table.

Comment: Question how otfen wil the ages change and second can there be less expensive one in the 4000 - 4999 range like  3500 - 3600 which also costs $4.65

Comment: I have only given the prices as an example, it will all depend on how much our local postage service charges to send a package 4000 to 4999 is on states postcode as is 2000 to 2999, as will be 3000 to 3999 it depends on what state the items are being sent to... There are about 19 different ranges of postcodes here and will only send/ ship within the country.  Postage is determined on where the recipient is - Close to major city is cheaper than outlying areas (Cheaper with-in CBD, more expensive in rural towns)

Comment: Postcodes could range like: 1000—1999, 2000—2599, 2619—2899, 2921—2999, 0200—0299, 2600—2618, 2900—2920, 3000—3999, 8000—8999, 4000—4999, 9000—9999, 5000—5799, 5800—5999, 6000—6797, 6800—6999, 7000—7799, 7800—7999, 0800—0899, 0900—0999 are the ranges of Postcodes, Some groups may cost the same as others.

Answer (score 0):

Try CASE https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Something like this:

```
SELECT   Postcode, Cost =  
      CASE 
         WHEN Postcode LIKE '4%' THEN 8.00  
         WHEN Postcode LIKE '2%' THEN 4.65   
         ELSE 'unknown'  
      END
```

or

```
    SELECT   Postcode, Cost =  
          CASE  
             WHEN Postcode  BETWEEN '1000' AND '1999' THEN 8.00  
             WHEN Postcode  BETWEEN '2000' AND '2999' THEN 4.65   
...
             ELSE 'unknown'  
          END
```